# How to set connectionstring for DbExtensions/SqlBuilder?

Tags: c#, sqlbuilder, dbextensions

I am using DbExtensions/SqlBuilder.md for my project. And during connection I am getting following Error.

> A default provider name must be provided using the
>   'DbExtensions:DefaultProviderName' key in the appSettings
>   configuration section.

My ConnectionString is in Session object.
Here is my Code.

```
Database db = new Database(HelperClass.ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got solution.
Add key in Web.config file.

```
 <add key="DbExtensions:DefaultProviderName" value ="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and it will work.